# How do I assign an Ubuntu user to SMTP service for authentication?

Tags: debian, smtp

I need to lock down my SMTP port with authentication. How do I assign a user to it that doesn't have root access?

Comment: Strange question. You cannot assign users to ports. Only a process with UID 0 or the capability CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE can bind to the SMTP port. After binding the root process can switch to a different user. I guess most SMTP daemons will abort when not running as root.

Comment: Which mail server are you using?

Comment: I am new to this environment and they use exim4. They need to make sure that smtpnauth is used.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is "SASL Authentication"

e.g. if  you are using postfix you could use the sasldb plugin:

http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#auxprop_sasldb